# After complete an registration form, how can i show an alert 'Your are done. click OK to login' and then when user click OK it will go to login page?

Tags: javascript

After complete an registration form, how can i show an alert 'Your are done. click OK to login' and then when user click OK it will go to login page?

> if($query){
>       echo ("
>       window.alert('Successfully Registered')
>       window.location.href='login.php';
>       ");  }

Comment: If you want people to help you you should show some examples of what code you currently have and what you tried already. This questions is way too vague.

Comment: if($query){
    echo ("<SCRIPT>
    window.alert('Successfully Registered')
    window.location.href='login.php';
    </SCRIPT>");
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

??? why not change the ok button to say "login", why do you need an alert ??

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I could not  comment until 50 rep So could you please explain how to do it?

Comment: Just stay around for a while until you have 50rep - a few good answers should do the trick. Sorry for the message, though: it was predefined as standard comment to "not an answer" in review queue. I upvoted your best answer to speed up the 50rep goal (it deserved upvote anyway). Good luck.